# breakable tcolorbox with empty/hidden interior and nonempty frame

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to define a breakable tcolorbox whose interior contains no color or other drawing code, so displays whatever color is behind it. [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) with the `skins` library has the options `interior empty` and `interior hidden` which control the drawing of the interior, though I struggling to understand the interaction between these keys and the corresponding `frame empty` and `frame hidden`. I would expect the former keys to print the frame surrounding the box's contents with nothing done to the interior, but instead the box is printed with a dark gray background.

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385976/208544), I see that we can get around this by setting both `frame empty` and `interior empty` then drawing the frame with `borderline`. This works for unbroken boxes, but if a box is broken then it seems the `frame empty` and `interior empty` keys are ignored and the tcolorbox defaults go into effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pagecolor{yellow!10}

\tcbset{enhanced}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  interior empty
  ]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  interior empty,
  frame empty % don't want hidden frame
  ]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  interior hidden
  ]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  interior hidden,
  frame hidden, % don't want hidden frame
  ]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  frame empty,
  interior empty,
  borderline={1pt}{0pt}{},
]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  breakable,
  frame empty,
  interior empty,
  borderline={1pt}{0pt}{},
]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\kant[1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: tcbox]

I'm probably misunderstanding what is really meant by "frame" and "interior", but is there a way to make a breakable tcolorbox with an empty interior?

#### Edit

As samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz points out in the comments, the "frame" is a filled rectangle behind the box, not a line drawn around it. This explains the output with `interior empty` and `interior hidden`.

I've also discovered that `breakable` does not interact nicely with `frame empty` and `interior empty` in general:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  breakable,
  interior empty,
  frame empty
  ]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\kant[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

This resets the frame and interior defaults when broken.

For context, I'm trying to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236230/208544) for emulating [`thmbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmbox) with tcolorbox to use the page background color, not the preset background color `white`, since this is the behavior of thmbox.

Comment: The normal frame of a tcolorbox is not a line, but a filled, slightly bigger rectangle behind the interior.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ah that makes sense

Comment: If the frame would be drawn as a line, one might run into problems at the transition from the interior to the frame. Depending on the pdfviewer, zoom etc. some users might see tiny gaps between them.

Comment: Can you add some background info why you need to see behind the tcolorbox? Are you using a background image?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz More info added

Comment: Will the background colour change between breaks?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I would expect not

Comment: Great, that makes things easier

Comment: Similar: [tcolorbox without background color (transparent)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287438). Short answer: setting `enhanced jigsaw, opacityback=0`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ This has the problem that on some pdf viewers, if `boxrule` (or `leftrule`, etc.) are set to zero, they still display as grey lines. See also my comments below samcarter's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706216/208544)

Comment: @mbert I reread your question and it seems to me the current question title "breakable tcolorbox with empty/hidden interior and nonempty frame" and the context "I'm trying to adapt this answer for emulating `thmbox` with `tcolorbox` ..." composed an X-Y problem. I added an answer to the question from context, not from question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is to read the docs :)

> Typically, the frame engine fills the complete box area with color and the other engines fill certain areas with other colors. [...] For certain boxes, a more delicate procedure is needed. E.g., if the box should be translucent, an already painted area cannot be made unpainted. Therefore, more elaborate frame engines saw holes into the frame where the interior area and optionally the title area will be painted. The resulting skins are called jigsaw skins.

So one just needs to use jigsaw box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced jigsaw,
  breakable,
  opacityback=0,
]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\kant[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is great! There is one problem though, that if the frame rule has zero width (say by adding `boxrule=0pt` to your example), then the outline of the frame still displays. Not sure if this is a pdf artifact or intended, but it is relevant in the thmbox example I mentioned since the frame is partially hidden

Comment: @mbert I think viewer issue. I can reproduce your problem in poppler-based viewers, but in e.g. mac preview, it works fine.

Comment: (and I still think you should accept your answer :)

Comment: Interesting. It shows in poppler and acrobat but not in pdf.js or pdfxchange. Thanks for identifying the issue!

Comment: In fact `\tikz\draw[line width=0pt](0,0)--(4,0);` produces a line in all pdf viewers I've tried. I wonder if this is intended behavior

Comment: @mbert pdfviewer try to be clever, most of them do some fancy stuff like "thin line enhancement" and whatever they call their features. I'm sure this is often useful, but sometimes not so much.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of actually making the tcolorbox transparent, you could make it *look* transparent by colouring it in the same colour as the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\pagecolor{yellow}

\tcbset{enhanced}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  breakable,
  colback=\thepagecolor
]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\kant[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is a good workaround. I was hoping for a "nicer" way that really makes the interior drawing code empty (then I could draw the `frame code` manually), but I don't think that's possible with `breakable`

Answer (score 3):

While `frame empty` and `interior empty` do not work as expected when given with `breakable`, they do work if given to the `extras` key. This way we can fake the frame with `borderline`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pagecolor{yellow!10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  breakable,
  extras={frame empty,interior empty},
  borderline={1pt}{0pt}{}
  ]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\kant[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: breakable box]

Comment: Nice! You should accept this answer as this will also work for users with background images etc.

Answer (score 3):

> For context, I'm trying to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236230/208544) for emulating [`thmbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmbox) with tcolorbox to use the page background color, not the preset background color `white`, since this is the behavior of thmbox.

It seems you need

```tex
\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        % ...
        % colback=white,
        % colframe=white,
        % colbacktitle=white,
        %% in order to imitate effect of "enhanced jigsaw, boxrule=0pt"
        frame engine=empty,
        interior titled engine=empty,
        interior engine=empty,
        extras broken={
          frame engine=empty,
          interior titled engine=empty,
          interior engine=empty
        },
        % ...
    }
}
```

[image]

Full example, based on the linked [@Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236230):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins, theorems}

\pagecolor{yellow!10}

\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        breakable,
        enhanced,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        % colback=white,
        % colframe=white,
        % colbacktitle=white,
        %% in order to imitate effect of "enhanced jigsaw, boxrule=0pt".
        %% or put the following three lines in "extras unbroken={...}"
        frame engine=empty,
        interior titled engine=empty,
        %% every theorem has a title, so this is just for completeness
        interior engine=empty,
        extras broken={
          frame engine=empty,
          interior titled engine=empty,
          interior engine=empty
        },
        coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        },
    S/.style={thmbox, 
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        },
    L/.style={thmbox, 
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);},
        },
    LQ/.style={thmbox, 
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
    },  
}

\newtcbtheorem[]{tcbthmbox}{Theorem}{thmbox}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[]{tcbSthmbox}{Theorem}{thmbox,S}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[]{tcbLthmbox}{Theorem}{thmbox,L}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[]{proof}{Démonstration}{thmbox,LQ}{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbthmbox}{First result}{}
\lipsum[3]
\end{tcbthmbox}

\begin{tcbSthmbox}{Important}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcbSthmbox}

\begin{tcbLthmbox}{Final}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcbLthmbox}

\begin{proof}{Proof}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```